# delete multiple arrays and update the state in redux

Tags: javascript, redux

i am trying to delete multiple documents and update the state in redux.

The data comes in as the following:

```
let data =[{id: 389, name: "doc6"},{id:490,name:"paul"},{id:502,name:"john"}]
```

The documentElId.id has the data that i want to delete.

The documentElId.id was the `[{id: 389, name: "doc6"},{id:490,name:"paul"}]`

I tried to do a foreach over the array and use filter remove the documents that i do not want.
I tried a few other things and i didnt work.

```
 case types.DeleteDocument:
    const data = [...state.currentDocument]
     let filteredData;   
     let updateDocument = 
      data.forEach(function (data, index) {
      filteredData =state.currentDocument.filter(data => data.id != action.documentElId.id)
      });
return {
        ...state,
        currentDocument: updateDocument,
        actionSuccessful: true
      }
```

Can anyone recommend the best way of doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you storing the result of `filter`?  Further, you're storing the result of `forEach` which is `undefined`

Comment: this works but i cant get it into an array: let data =[{id: 389, name: "doc6"},{id:490,name:"paul"},{id:502,name:"john"}]
let filtereddata;
data.forEach(function(element){
 filtereddata = data.filter(doc=>doc.id !=389) 
});